# Using CodeIgniter built-in form validator class without an actual form submission

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

Is it possible to validate a set of data (an array) with the **form validation class** in **CodeIdniter**? i.e. when there his no form submitted.

If it's not possible, what other way could I validate this data using the **set of validation rules** written in form_validation config file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can validate any data using form validation, I have never tried, but it should work if you assign to $_POST array values manually (without submitting form) and then try to validate it.

Answer (score 1):

From the manual, under the section [rule reference](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference),

> Note: These rules can also be called
>   as discrete functions. For example:
>
> ```
> $this->form_validation->required($string);
> ```